# Return parent of a node in a binary tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I want to implement a recursive function in C where the return value is the parent of a node in a binary tree. As parameters I have `t`, which is the tree in question and the character `n`, the name of the node. I want to find the parent of this node. I tried to do this, but it didn't work.

```
Tree*
tree_par (Tree* t, char n)
{
    if (!tree_null(t))
    {
        if (info(t->lft) || info(t->rgt) == n)
           return t;

        else
        {
            tree_par(t->lft, n);
            tree_par(t->rgt, n);
        }
    }
}
```

The function `info` returns the name of the node and the function `tree_null` checks if the tree is empty. Here is the tree structure:

```
struct tree
{
    struct tree *lft, *rgt; //left node and right node
    char n;
};
```

info function:

```
char
info (Tree* t)
{
    return t->n;
}
```

tree_null function:

```
int
tree_null (Tree* t)
{
    return (t == NULL);
}
```

Comment: Note: the function returns a random value to the caller if `tree_null()` returns true. (your compiler should warn you about this)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (info(t->lft) || info(t->rgt) == n)
           return t;
```

Here's the problem. The two sides of the `||` operator are independent one from the other, so this is NOT equal to

```
if (info(t->lft) == n || info(t->rgt) == n)
```

which is what you wanted.

You have to put the equality test on both sides of the `||`

```
if (info(t->lft) == n || info(t->rgt) == n)
           return t;
```

Edit, also please note that if you do

```
 else
        {
            tree_par(t->lft, n);
            tree_par(t->rgt, n);
        }
```

You are actually discarding the return value of the recursive function call, you need to change it to check which one of the two recursive call (if any) was successful; also, don't forget to add something like a `return NULL` for an empty tree, otherwise you will get undefined return values.

It will be similar to this:

```
Tree* tree_par (Tree* t, char n)
{
    if (!tree_null(t))
    {
        if ((info(t->lft) == n) || (info(t->rgt) == n))
           return t;
        else
        {
            Tree tt*;
            tt=tree_par(t->lft, n);
            if (tt==NULL)
                tt= tree_par(t->rgt, n);
            return tt;
        }
    }
    else
       return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post also the `info` function?

Comment: About your edit, i was suspicious of this problem inside else, but i sincerely don't know how to fix it. I'm new to recursion

Comment: I'm changing my answer to show you a possible solution

Comment: it returns the wrong node. always the root node. this also happened in my original function so basically nothing changed.

Comment: @jaryl The final code's `if` condition was wrong, try checking it now.

Comment: Also, your `info` function should check whether `t` is `NULL`, since you don't check if before calling it.